# Operador => em metodos C#

Tags: c#

Possuo as dúvidas:

Qual a utilidade e o nome do operador em negrito abaixo?

```
private double ConverterRadianos(double dblValorAngulo) **=>** (dblValorAngulo * 0.0174532925);
```

Comment: Não é um operador, é só sintaxe normal da linguagem.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda amigo!